# Adjusting UILabel width in XIB

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, uilabel

I am trying to add two `UILabels` in a container view and adjusting the size of the labels according to the content inside. Everything is working fine except for one thing. I want the width of `labels` to be adjusted according to the first label having `Text A` and the number of lines of second label should change if the content in second label is more than first label. Here are the constraints for labels.

[image: Constraints for Text A]

[image: Constraints for Text B Text B]

[image: Output view]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure label B has a width constraint (it currently does not so its width will expand indefinitely to fit its content)  then ensure label B has `numberOfLines` set to zero. That setting is available in Interface Builder.

I'm assuming from your constraints that your container has a fixed width and that its height is free to expand to fit the labels.

Comment: I can not keep the width of container as fixed since I want to expand the width of the container according to the width of label A's content and height according to the total of label A and label B. I have kept number of lines as 0 for label B.

Comment: I see. In that case I would increase label A's horizontal content hugging and compression resistance both to 1000.